# QML move inside zoomed charts with Middle button

Tags: qt, charts, qml, mouse

I'm working with QML Charts. I have now a plot  :

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtCharts 2.0

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    ChartView {
        id: chartView
        anchors.fill: parent
        theme: ChartView.ChartThemeBrownSand
        antialiasing: true

        LineSeries {
            name: "LineSeries"
            XYPoint { x: 0; y: 0 }
            XYPoint { x: 1.1; y: 2.1 }
            XYPoint { x: 1.9; y: 3.3 }
            XYPoint { x: 2.1; y: 2.1 }
            XYPoint { x: 2.9; y: 4.9 }
            XYPoint { x: 3.4; y: 3.0 }
            XYPoint { x: 4.1; y: 3.3 }
        }

        MouseArea{
            anchors.fill: parent
            onDoubleClicked: chartView.zoomReset();
        }
    }
}
```

I can zoom in and out by using the ZoomIn(QRect)

```
var r = Qt.rect(x, y, w, h)
chartView.zoomIn(r)
```

after zooming done i need to move in zoomed plot with pressing middle button (wheel) and shift my place Right or left in chartView.

how i can get pressed middle button position and move ploted series based on that positions ?!

**EDIT :**
middle click option is not important it can be right click . but how to detect it is still pressing and get position of that and set it on ZoomIn(Qrec).

Comment: Have you checked the MouseArea [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-mousearea.html#pressedButtons-prop) to figure out how to read middle button presses?

Comment: i read docs but still i need some help . it's little blur for me .

Comment: i think i should use ZoomIn(QRect) based on middle button position or should i use drag ?! so its little confiusing  for me

Comment: what is the optimal way ..

Comment: here middle click is not important it can be right click  . but how to detect it is still pressing and get position of that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use 2 params :

```
property bool btnClicked: false
property int mouseLastX
```

then on pressed :

```
onPressed: {
    if (mouse.button == Qt.LeftButton) {
        btnClicked = true
        console.log("down")
    }
}
```

then on Release :

```
onReleased: {
    btnClicked = false
}
```

and finally do what you want in position changed (while dragging):

```
    onPositionChanged: {

    if (btnClicked) {
        console.log("dragging")

        // zoome based on mouse position :
        var ch = mouseX - mouseLastX
        console.log(ch)
        mouseLastX = mouseX

        chartView.zoomIn(Qt.rect(chartView.plotArea.x + ch, 0,
                                 chartView.plotArea.width,
                                 chartView.plotArea.height))
    }
}
```